# Existe sinônimos de "foo", "bar", "baz", ... em português?

Tags: tradução, palavra-para-ideia

É muito comum em exemplos de código, usar *foo, bar* e/ou *baz* como nome/valor de variáveis, funções, classes, etc., onde esses nomes e valores são irrelevantes

Esses termos vem do inglês, mas no português tem algo equivalente ou semelhante?

Comment: O termo e fubar, na minha opinião. The etymology of foo is obscure. Its use in connection with bar is generally traced to the World War II military slang FUBAR, later bowdlerised to foobar. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar Quer dizer: placeholder. ou seja: marcador de posição

Answer (score 1):

A origem dessas palavras é bastante incerta, portanto é um tanto complicado tentar traduzi-las, já que não têm um significado tão bem definido.

Elas têm uma função de representar um substantivo genérico (chamado de **variável metassintática** ou **metavariável** em programação), o qual pode ser empregado para definir qualquer coisa. Nesse quesito, poderíamos dizer que é equivalente a "fulano", "sicrano" e "beltrano", que têm a mesma função, mas não se aplicam tão bem à programação.

Esse tipo genérico de metavariável é muito comum em inglês por conta do programação utilizar o inglês como idioma principal, por isso, são raras as metavariáveis genéricas em outras línguas. Em japonês, por sua vez, existe o ホゲホゲ (hogehoge) que funciona como termo genérico (assim como "fulano" ou "foo").

Literalmente falando, Foo poderia ter vindo do ideograma chinês 福 (fu) que, por sua vez, significa "benção". Por outro lado especula-se que Foo também resuma o termo **File Or Object**, podendo ser traduzido como **Arquivo ou Objeto**.

**Bar**, por sua vez, pode ser traduzido como bar ou barra.

Comment: Parece-me que qualquer origem de *foo, bar* e *baz* é pouco relevante, e os nomes são essencialmente arbitrários. Então em português qualquer coisa serve, como simplesmente usar *foo, bar* e *baz*. Mas *ful, sic* e *bel* teriam a sua piada.